# Prevent URL parameters binding

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Wab API method defined as such:

```
[HttpGet, Route( "{type}" )]
public SomeClass Search( string type )
```

so when called as

```
GET  .../Widget?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

`type` is `Widget`. If the GET url includes a `type` parameter though:

```
GET  .../Widget?type=Gadget&param2=value2
```

then `type` is `Gadget` - that is not what I want.

Is there a way to prevent this binding to happen - so that I get always `Widget` regardless of the URL parameters?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `ValueProvider` attribute on the parameter will allow you to specify a provider. There are other options as well for configuring the source of the arguments.

See: http://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-and-greedy-query-string-parameter-binding/